# Compute difference between rows prior to and following to the specific row_pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to find the difference between rows prior to and following to the specific row. Specifically, I have the following dataset:

```
 Number of rows       A             
 1                    4             
 2                    2             
 3                    2             
 4                    3             
 5                    2
```

I should get the following data:

```
 Number of rows      A        B
 1                   4        NaN (since there is not row before this row)
 2                   2        2   (4-2)
 3                   2       -1   (2-3)
 4                   3        0   (2-2)
 5                   2        NaN (since there is not row after this row)
```

As you can see, each row in column B, equal the difference between previous and following rows in column A. For example, second row in column B, equal the difference between value in the first row in column A and value in the third row in column A. IMPORTANT POINT: I do not need only previous and following. I should find the difference between previous 2 and the following 2 rows. I meant the value in row Number 23 in column B will be equal the difference between the value in row Number 21 in column A and the value in row Number 25 in column A. I use the previous and the following rows for simplicity.
I hope I could explain it.

Comment: Have you looked at `shift`?

Comment: Note actually. How can I apply shift?

Comment: For simplicity, I use only previous and the following rows. So, the value in row Number 2 in Column B, equals the difference between the value in row Number 1 and row number 3 in column A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you need a *centered* [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html) window. You can specify that with the arg `center=True`

```
>>> df.A.rolling(3, center=True).apply(lambda s: s[0]-s[-1])

0    NaN
1    2.0
2   -1.0
3    0.0
4    NaN
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

This approach works for any window. Notice that this is a *centered window*, so the size of the window has to be `N+N+1` (where `N` is the number of lookback and lookforward rows, and you add 1 to account for the value in the middle). Thus, the general formula is

```
window = 2*N + 1
```

If you need 2 rows before and 2 after, then `N = 2`. if you need 5 and 5, `N=5` (and window = 11) etc. *The apply lambda stays the same.*

Comment: So, in that case, I want to find the difference between the previous 5th and the following 5th row values, then the code should like that: df1a.Price.rolling(10, center=True).apply(lambda s: s[4]-s[-5]).  Am I right?

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Let the series (i.e. DataFrame column) be `s`.

You want:

```
s.shift(1) - s.shift(-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use .shift on the column (series) where you want to run your calculation.

With shift(1) you get the previous row, with shift(-1) you get the next row.

from there you need to calculate `previous - next`

```
>>> s = pd.Series([4,2,2,3,2])
>>> s
0    4
1    2
2    2
3    3
4    2
dtype: int64
# previous 
>>> s.shift(1)
0    NaN
1    4.0
2    2.0
3    2.0
4    3.0
dtype: float64
# next 
>>> s.shift(-1)
0    2.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    2.0
4    NaN
dtype: float64
# previous - next 
>>> s.shift(1)-s.shift(-1)
0    NaN
1    2.0
2   -1.0
3    0.0
4    NaN
dtype: float64
```